# Regular expression to replace inner credit card numbers with X's?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, sails.js

Is it possible to use regex to replace all characters in a card number with an X, except for the left-outer 4-digits and right-outer 4-digits, when the card number varies in length between 15-19 characters?

I've been searching but couldn't find a solution with variable card lengths.

I'm building a sails.js app.

(Note: For those of you with PCI-compliance worries, I'm not storing credit card numbers and it's not a live application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this pattern

```
(?<=\d{4})\d(?=\d{4})
```

and replace w/ `X`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/195)

```
(?<=            # Look-Behind
  \d            # <digit 0-9>
  {4}           # (repeated {4} times)
)               # End of Look-Behind
\d              # <digit 0-9>
(?=             # Look-Ahead
  \d            # <digit 0-9>
  {4}           # (repeated {4} times)
)               # End of Look-Ahead
```

---

if your engine does not support look-behind use this pattern instead

```
^(\d{4})\d(?=\d{4})|\d(?=\d{4})
```

Note: will only work properly for 9+ digit numbers
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/196)

Comment: Hey, for some reason JavaScript doesn't like `?<=` and it throws an error and fails. Any idea how to make that work?  In particular, it doesn't like the `<`. See: https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/195#javascript

Comment: @alphabravo, cool, yeah that works great. Credit/debit card numbers are 12-19 digits so that works well.

Comment: @ngDeveloper, if you think it's solved, please mark my answer as such.

Comment: @alphabravo Tested and it works. Marked as accepted.